# Why "Integrate[Abs[x1 - x2], {x1, 0, t}, {x2, 0, t}]" get wrong output?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

To verify the following double integral
$$
\int_0^t{\int_0^t{\left| x_1-x_2 \right|\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2}}=\frac{t^3}{3}
$$
The MATHEMATICA (12.0.0 on Win10-64) got the following wrong output

```
In[1]:= Integrate[Abs[x1 - x2], {x1, 0, t}, {x2, 0, t}]
Out[1]= 0
```

Comment: What version are you using? I get a warning and the t^3/3 result you expect. I am on MMA 12.3.1 on Win10-64

Comment: `Integrate[Abs[x1 - x2], {x1, 0, t}, {x2, 0, t}, Assumptions -> t > 0] ` evaluates the correct result without warning

Comment: `Integrate[Abs[x1 - x2], {x1, x2} ∈ Rectangle[{0, 0}, {t, t}]]`

Comment: OK in 13.1 on Windows 10 and  no warning.

Comment: `Integrate[Abs[x1-x2],{x1,0,t},{x2,0,t},GenerateConditions->False]` gives a warning and the result `0`, in V12.3.

Comment: In 13.1 on Windows 10 `Integrate[Abs[x1 - x2], {x1, 0, t}, {x2, 0, t}, 
 GenerateConditions -> True]` performs `t^3/3`, but `NIntegrate[Abs[x1 - x2], {x1, 0, I}, {x2, 0, I}]` results in `-0.333333 + 0. I`.

Comment: I am on MMA 12.0.0 on Win10-64. I think my MMA's version is too old.

Comment: Please don't use the bugs tag until the community agrees (see [tag:bugs] for an explanation).

Comment: @MichailE2: The bugs tag is added by me again.

Comment: @MarcoB: The bugs tag is added by me again. Let us call things by their proper names.

Comment: @MarcoB: See [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/svpr60si3269n7b/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202022-11-15%2008.21.46.png?dl=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f1[t_] = Integrate[Abs[x1 - x2], {x1, 0, t}, {x2, 0, t}]

(* t^3/3 *)
```

This indicates that the sign of the result depends on the sign of `t`. For example,

```
f1 /@ Range[-2, 2]

(* {-(8/3), -(1/3), 0, 1/3, 8/3} *)
```

However, this does not agree with the use of actual values

```
Integrate[Abs[x1 - x2], {x1, 0, #}, {x2, 0, #}] & /@ Range[-2, 2]

(* {8/3, 1/3, 0, 1/3, 8/3} *)
```

Assuming `t` is real corrects the result

```
f1R[t_] = Integrate[Abs[x1 - x2], {x1, 0, t}, {x2, 0, t},
  Assumptions -> Element[t, Reals]]
```

[image]

```
f1R /@ Range[-2, 2]

(* {8/3, 1/3, 0, 1/3, 8/3} *)
```

`f1R` can also be expressed as `Sign[t] t^3/3`

```
f1R[t] == Sign[t] t^3/3 // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Using an alternate representation for `Abs` of a real value also gives the wrong result

```
Assuming[Element[{x1, x2}, Reals],
 Abs[x1 - x2] == Sqrt[(x1 - x2)^2] // Simplify]

(* True *)

Integrate[Sqrt[(x1 - x2)^2], {x1, 0, t}, {x2, 0, t}]

(* t^3/3 *)
```

However, in this case the assumption does not correct the result.

```
Integrate[Sqrt[(x1 - x2)^2], {x1, 0, t}, {x2, 0, t}, 
 Assumptions -> Element[t, Reals]]

(* t^3/3 *)
```

Using actual values give the correct results.

```
Integrate[Sqrt[(x1 - x2)^2], {x1, 0, #}, {x2, 0, #}] & /@
 Range[-2, 2]

(* {8/3, 1/3, 0, 1/3, 8/3} *)
```

Alternatively, using `RealAbs`

```
Integrate[RealAbs[x1 - x2], {x1, 0, t}, {x2, 0, t}]
```

[image]

In this case, an assumption is needed to fully evaluate the integral and provide the correct result.

```
Integrate[RealAbs[x1 - x2], {x1, 0, t}, {x2, 0, t}, 
 Assumptions -> Element[t, Reals]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Wolfram Product Feedback CASE: 4985229 "It does appear that Integrate is not handling this input properly. I have forwarded an issue report to our developers..."

Comment: Thank you very much!